# Arithmetical operations in certain script language

Tags: c, parsing, scripting

I am working on certain script language. Values containing structure is

```
struct myvar
{
 char  name[NAMELEN];
 int   type;
 void* value;
}
type = 0  --> int* value
type = 1  --> char* value
type = 2  --> float* value
```

I faced some problem with arithmetic operations. It seems that I need to commit all sorts of type conversions over every single operation, that develops into writing a whole bunch of code for each of them, as in:

```
case 0:  // "="
 if(factor1.name)
 {
    if((factor1.type == 1) && (factor2.type==1))
    {
        free(factor1.value);
        int len = (strlen((STRING)factor2.value)+1)*sizeof(char);
        factor1.value = malloc(len);
        memcpy(factor1.value,factor2.value,len);
    }
    else if((factor1.type == 2) && (factor2.type==2))
    *(FLOAT*)factor1.value = *(FLOAT*)factor2.value;
    else if((factor1.type == 0) && (factor2.type==0))
    *(INTEGER*)factor1.value = *(INTEGER*)factor2.value;
    else if((factor1.type == 0) && (factor2.type==2))
    *(INTEGER*)factor1.value = *(FLOAT*)factor2.value;
    else if((factor1.type == 2) && (factor2.type==0))
    *(FLOAT*)factor1.value = *(INTEGER*)factor2.value;
    else
     GetNextWord("error");
 }
 break;
```

Is there some way to avoid this tiresome procedure? Otherwise I have no choice but to copy-paste this piece of code for each of "=","~","+","-","*","/","%",">","<",">=","<=","==","~=","AND","OR"

Comment: not an answer, but do you aware that you have the same condition twice? `((factor1.type == 1) && (factor2.type==1))`

Comment: @MByD, I think the very first pair is supposed to be 0,0, since it is doing a string copy, and type 0 is string.

Comment: Oh yes, my fault. Thank you for marking, I just put it from scratch while being concern about the main problem.

Comment: `if(factor1.name)` ? can factor1.name be "false"? According to me, it will be always true, since factor.name will be always a not-NULL pointer...

Comment: It may be false if it is a constant instead of variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about writing 3 `toType` functions:

```
char* toType0(myvar* from)
{
   if (from->type == 0) return (char*)(from->value);
   else if (from->type == 1) return itoa((int*)from->value);
   else...
}
int toType1(myvar* from)
{
   //convert to int...
}
```

Then in your conversion routines you can do:

```
 switch (factor1.type)
 {
    case 0:
     { char* other = toType0(&factor2);
     //assign or add or whatever....
     };
     break;
     case 1:
     { int other = toType1(&factor2);
     //assign or add or whatever....
     };
     break;
     ...
  }
```

Comment: If you want to disallow certain operations like float to string, just modify the `toType` functions to return an error code if the conversion is illegal.

Comment: Although it is not a complete solution, I also think @blagovest's suggstion to use a union instead of a void* is a good one.  It will remove lots of ugly casting from your code.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `union` instead of a `struct` for the values:

```
struct myvar {
  enum {
    STRING, INT, FLOAT,
  } type;

  union {
    char  strval[NAMELEN];
    int   intval;
    float fltval;
  } val;
};
```

and then in executing the assignment operator in your scripting language you just do:

```
factor1 = factor2;
```

To fetch the right value based on the type you would do:

```
switch (operand.type) {
  case STRING:
    printf("%s", operand.val.strval);
    break;

  case INT:
    printf("%d", operand.val.intval);
    break;

  case FLOAT:
    printf("%f", operand.val.fltval);
    break;
}
```

Comment: This would definitely help for assignment, but what about other operations?

Comment: I need a certain type variable, not all together.

Answer (score 2):

I would propose the following: when applying an operation, you should first coerce the operand types. E.g., if your operand types are int and float, you should coerce int value to a float one, and continue with the float version of the operation. The coercion is the same (or almost the same) for all the operations. With such an approach, you have much less cases to consider.